# How to create a Bitcoin Transaction With Protocoin

Tags: transactions, python

Please how do I create a btc transaction and broadcast it with protocoin library? I want to create a transaction that will relay to the node without validating inputs and outputs. Of course I know the transaction will not get confirmed. I just want it to be broadcasted for a while. 
Does anyone know any way I can use to do this? If there are other simpler methods to do this, I would also appreciate that.

Comment: what is protocoin? Have you attempted anything, yet, please share what you've tried and the result.

Comment: Your node will discard the invalid transaction and not broadcast it. If it does broadcast it, its peers will ban it for sending invalid data. I think you may get better help if you provide more background information on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate this, but without using the software advertised there. https://youtu.be/s8Ij1oPYBsU